# Read an indefinite amount of lines until user hits enter (twice) in C

Tags: c, scanf, readline

I can't get around this problem. I need the user to type a string then hit enter, then another string. When he/she is done hit enter once more (this last string would only have \n character so I know when to stop).

```
char * buff = malloc (100);

 printf("Type in strings, to finish hit enter\n");

 do{
       scanf (" %[^\n]",buff);
       //do some other stuff with the string
  } while(*buff);            

  printf("You have finished typing strings\n");
```

This approach I came up with is no use for me, since the [^\n] command is telling the function to read everything but the \n meaning that the \n is kept in the console buffer. If I simply do

```
while(*buff)
  {
      scanf ("%s",buff);
  }
```

if I hit enter it does nothing.
Any other approach?

Comment: use `__getch` to check for a `\n`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, `scanf` is actually looking for characters.  What you want is `gets` (to get a line).

[edit] as pointed out by Daniel Fischer:

> `gets` has (at last) been removed from the language. Even before, the
>   man page has for a long time said **Never use `gets()`**

Looks like my advice was not the best.  I guess this means use `fgets`, as it protects against buffer overrun.  Unlike `gets`, the newline character(s) will also be stored in the string and it is the programmer's responsibility to check for them.

```
const size_t bufsize = 100;
char buf[bufsize];

while( fgets(buf, bufsize, stdin) != NULL )
{
    if( buf[0] == '\n' ) break;

    /* Do something with your string... */
}
```

Comment: By the way, in case it's not obvious...  The strings you get from using `gets` may be different from those you get using `scanf`.  If you want individual words from that line (like `scanf` would give you) then you'll need to parse them out (with `sscanf` or `strtok`)

Comment: `gets` has (at last) been removed from the language. Even before, the man page has for a long time said **Never use `gets()`**.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for pointing that out.  It always seemed a bit lazy, but good enough for throw-away apps.  I will update my answer to be more useful.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, if you are the only one to ever use the programme, it's a risk you can take, but if anybody else may use it, it's too dangerous.

Comment: thanks for your help guys! as this is only for collage and more specifically for learning pointers, it wouldn't be a problem if I use gets. but nevertheless I will use the other function, just for the sake of practicing both approaches.
Once again, thank you :-)

Answer (score -1):

Besides what paddy pointed out (use gets to get a whole line), the condition

```
while(*buff);
```

won't ever be false, unless the user input would be a null character (as in ASCII value 0). The line break character (\n) has an ASCII value of 10, which evaluates to `true` in conditional statements.

Try this:

```
while(strlen(*buff) > 0);
```

Comment: Dunno who downvoted you without providing comment, but I'll provide one.  `gets` does not return the newline.  Still, it often pays to check (especially with all those CRLFs and their variants running wild out in the badlands).  A simple function to check if all string characters are whitespace would be sufficient.